# Android Studio Emulator gives error when running the project

Tags: java, android, emulation

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a JRE, but gradle works on JDK, so download a jdk (jdk 1.8.0 whatever) and a quick fix would be just merge contents of jdk-1.8.x/ folder into \Java\jre1.8.0_301

It's not a clean solution but it should solve your problem

A clean solution would be to uninstall jre and install a jdk or just install a jdk and set classpath and javapath to jdk instead of jre